# C# parsing JSON array overwrites values on the list

Tags: c#, json, serialization, arraylist

Im having problem with deserializing json file into my class.
Json file looks like this:

```
    { 
    "DataFile": {
        "header":{
            "version": "123",
            "date": "01.01.01",         
        },
        "customer": {
            "fID": "12-35-58",
            "nameCust": "CompanyName",
            "adressCust":{
                "zip": "0000",
                "city": "Foovile",
                "streetNr": "1",
                "post": "FoovilePost",
                "street": "DunnoStr",
            },
        },
        "content": [
                {
                    "invoice":{
                        "DFID":"538",
                    },
                    "invoice":{
                        "DFID":"500",
                    },
                    "invoice":{
                        "DFID":"550",
                    },
                    "receipt":{
                        "DFID":"758",
                    },
                    "receipt":{
                        "DFID":"75",
                    },
                }               
            ],

    }
    }
```

Everything before content array deserializes fine,so to keep things clear I'll skip parts of my class. Relevant bit looks like this:

```
class DFFile
{
    public DF Df { get; set; }
}

class DF
{
    public Header header { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public List<DFContent> content { get; set; }
}
class DFContent
{
    public Invoice invoice { get; set; }
    public Receipt receipt { get; set; }
}
class Invoice
{
    public int DFID { get; set; }
}
class Receipt
{
    public int DFID { get; set; }
}
```

And i deserialize into DFFile instance like this:

```
DFFile sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DFFile>(json);
```

My problem is that it deserializes without errors but sample.DF.content have only one element that have invoice and receipt with last id of each type. And result I'm looking for is list where there is new element for each item of json content array.
I can change my class but way this json is build is set in stone, can't do anything about it and have to deal with it.

Is there any way to stop it changing last element of content and add new one instead?

Comment: content has an array of one object, and the keys you're entering are the same so they are being overwritten.

Comment: Can you change your class structure?

Comment: @Jamie, yes that was the problem here. I dont actually have correct JSON files yet, I only have JSON Schema, so to test I created my own test json and messed up there. Thanks for quick answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content is set up to hold an array but you only have one item in it which has three invoice and two receipt values. Assuming you want your DFContent to hold either a receipt or invoice, change it to look like this:

```
 "content": [
                {"invoice":{
                        "DFID":"538",
                }},
                {"invoice":{
                        "DFID":"500",
                }},
                {"invoice":{
                        "DFID":"550",
                }},
                {"receipt":{
                        "DFID":"758",
                }},
                {"receipt":{
                        "DFID":"75",
                }}               
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot change the JSON I assumed that you can change your class structure.

Please consider this classes:

```
class DF
{
    // Other properties...
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FunnyListConverter))]
    public List<Content> content { get; set; }
}

class Content
{
    public int DFID { get; set; }
}

class Invoice : Content
{
}
class Receipt : Content
{
}
```

And here is the FunnyListConverter:

```
public class FunnyListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var content = new List<Content>();
        var currentType = "";
        Invoice currentInvoice = null;
        Receipt currentReceipt = null;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (reader.Value?.ToString() == "invoice")
            {
                currentInvoice = new Invoice();
                currentType = "invoice";
            }
            if (reader.Value?.ToString() == "receipt")
            {
                currentReceipt = new Receipt();
                currentType = "receipt";
            }
            if (reader.Path.Contains("DFID") && reader.Value?.ToString() != "DFID")
            {
                switch (currentType)
                {
                    case "invoice":
                        currentInvoice.DFID = int.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
                        content.Add(currentInvoice);
                        currentInvoice = null;
                        break;
                    case "receipt":
                        currentReceipt.DFID = int.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
                        content.Add(currentReceipt);
                        currentReceipt = null;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return content;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
          }
            if (reader.Value?.ToString() == "receipt")
            {
                currentReceipt = new Receipt();
                currentType = "receipt";
            }
            if (reader.Path.Contains("DFID") && reader.Value?.ToString() != "DFID")
            {
                switch (currentType)
                {
                    case "invoice":
                        currentInvoice.DFID = int.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
                        content.Add(currentInvoice);
                        currentInvoice = null;
                        break;
                    case "receipt":
                        currentReceipt.DFID = int.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
                        content.Add(currentReceipt);
                        currentReceipt = null;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return content;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, that was the approach I was trying but couldn't get it to work. I'll keep your answer for future reference as I'm new to the JSON deserialization. But actual problem was my test json file, as I only have json schema for now, I created my own for testing and messed up {} in the array. Again sorry for taking your time and thanks for quick answer. +1